# Как подключить библиотеку fannj в android studio?

Tags: java, android, библиотеки, fann

Как я только не пытался, не получалось. Были такие ошибки: При запуске приложения выбрасывает ошибку:

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/android-aarch64/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path (.)

Объясните алгоритм действий

Вот либа: https://github.com/krenfro/fannj

Comment: Посмотрите тут ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808813/3212712

Comment: Там указан путь, куда нужно вставлять файл. Двух последних папок в этом пути у меня нет

Comment: Попробуйте их создать

Comment: Увы, не помогло

Comment: Боюсь, что других мыслей у меня нет(